# Read metadata with ExifTool

Tags: java, image, metadata, adobe-illustrator, exiftool

I'm trying to read illustrator file metadata value by using Exiftool. I tried as per below.

```
File[] images = new File("filepath").listFiles();
ExifTool tool = new ExifTool(Feature.STAY_OPEN);
for(File f : images) {
    if (f.toString().contains(".ai"))
    {
        System.out.println("test "+tool.getImageMeta(f, Tag.DATE_TIME_ORIGINAL));
    }
}
tool.close();
```

Above code not printing any value. I even tried this.

```
public static final File[] IMAGES = new File("filepath").listFiles();
ExifTool tool = new ExifTool(Feature.STAY_OPEN);
for (File f : IMAGES) {
System.out.println("\n[" + f.getName() + "]");
System.out.println(tool.getImageMeta(f, Format.NUMERIC,
Tag.values()));
}
```

Which only prints `{IMAGE_HEIGHT=2245, IMAGE_WIDTH=5393}`. How do I call metadata values using Exiftool. Any advices and references links are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given API, it either;

1-does not contain the tag you are looking for

2-the file itself might not have that tag filled

3-you might want to recreate your own using a more general tag command when calling `exiftool.exe`

Look in the source code and find the `enum` containing all the tags available to the API, that'll show you what you're restricted to. But yeah, you might want to consider making your own class similar to the one you're using. I'm in the midst of doing the same. That way you can store the tags in perhaps a set or `HashMap` instead of an `enum` and therefore be much less limited in tag choice. Then, all you have to do is write the commands for the tags you want to the process's OutputStream and then read the results from the InputStream.